# Reduce width of HStack SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a chat app, but having difficulties with the HStack. The border I have is going over the edge of the view so the full rounded rectangle isn't shown.

[image: Text field]

The code I have for the TextField and HStack is this.

```swift
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CustomTextField(placeholder: Text("Enter your message"), text: $message)

            Button {
                messagesManager.sendMessage(message: message)
                message = ""
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding(10)
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 0)
        .border(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(20)
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    var placeholder: Text
    @Binding var text: String
    var editingChanged: (Bool) -> () = {_ in}
    var commit: () -> () = {}
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty {
                placeholder
                    .opacity(0.5)
            }
            TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find out how to reduce the length of the HStack so the whole of the rounded rectangle will show, as well as increasing the size of the button to fill up more space within the shape.

Comment: Actually your ordering for `.padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 0)
        .border(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(20)` is wrong . You should use padding after corner radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overlay` with `RoundedRectangle` for the border with a corner radius. I have added leading padding to your `CustomTextField` so that it will look proper and horizontal padding to your `HStack` after adding `overlay`.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        CustomTextField(placeholder: Text("Enter your message"), text: $message)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
        
        
        Button {
            //messagesManager.sendMessage(message: message)
            message = ""
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .padding(10)
                .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .stroke(.gray)
    )
    .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO3yT.png)